# SwiftUI navigation decision based on a sheet view presenting 2 choice

Tags: swiftui, binding, navigation, state

I am presenting a "wizard" that will be detecting a BLE device and then if it is the correct one the last view will ask if we want to register or skip.

Edit:{
the view order is: MainView presenting in fullScreenCover a first info view informing on how to detect the BLE device then this one pushes a second view with some info on the nearest BLE device and it is in this view that we have the fork where I am presenting a sheet to ask if the user wants to continue and register the BLE device or skip.

So MAIN > INFOView -> BLE detection (> Register or skip ? RegisterView : Destack to main)
}

I have that last view come up as a sheet it has 2 buttons, the first one as mentioned says "Register" and the other one says "skip". If the user presses the register then we dismiss the sheet and navigate to a view that is gathering personal info to register the BLE device. on the other hand, if the user chooses to skip then the wizard need to de-stack back over to the main view.

Normally in UIKit I would just have a delegate inform me of the choice then if skip was selected. I would call pop to root view controller, otherwise, if the register option was selected I would dismiss the sheet view and then navigate to one more final view and get the user registered.

In SwiftUI I do not know how to deal with that navigation fork. I tried using PassthroughSubject but then I have to set the PassthroughSubject var as a state var and in the end, I just did not get the call back from sending in the selection.

Tried binding then Was hoping to make an onReceive but then it is asking for a publisher and that felt wrong to create a publisher just for that.

I am wondering g what is the best way do take care of this in. swiftUI ?

edit:
this is the code (updated with the replay from @Predrag Samardzic) for the view that shows the info on the BLE device (smart bike) and will push at first a request to know if the user wants to register or not, then if yes push that registration screen if not dismiss the entire stack.

```
struct A18BikeDiscoveryView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var bleManager: ArgonBLEManager
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
private let shouldShowRegistration = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    @State var isSheetPresented = false
    @State var isRegistrationPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        NavigationLink(
            destination: A18RegistrationQuestionairy(QuestionairyViewModel()),
            isActive: $isRegistrationPresented
        ) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        A18ImageTextBanner(text: NSLocalizedString("bike_discovery_view_title", comment: ""))
            .padding(.bottom, 35)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        if let value = bleManager.model?.bikeInfo?.bikeModel{
            Text(value)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .scaledFont(.largeTitle)
        }
        
        Image("subitoBike")
            .resizable()
            .frame(minWidth: 0334, idealWidth: 334, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 223, idealHeight: 223, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
        
        Divider()
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Text("bike_discovery_view_year_created")
                if let v = bleManager.model?.bikeInfo?.year{
                    Text(v)
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Text("bike_discovery_view_model_size")
                Text("\(getSizeFromSerial())")
            }
            HStack{
                Text("bike_discovery_view_bike_serial_number")
                if let v = bleManager.model?.bikeInfo?.bikeSerialNumber {
                    Text(v)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 66, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        Divider()
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
        Button(action: {
            isSheetPresented = true
        }, label: {
            Text("bike_discovery_view_bike_pairing_button_title")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        })
        .buttonStyle(A18RoundButtonStyle(bgColor: .red))
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $isSheetPresented,
            onDismiss: {
                if shouldShowRegistration.value {
                    isRegistrationPresented = true
                }},
            content: {
                A18BikeParingSelection(shouldShowRegistration: shouldShowRegistration)
            })
        .onReceive(shouldShowRegistration) { shouldShowRegistration in
            isSheetPresented = false
            
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            bleManager.disconect()
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("bike_discovery_view_bike_pairing_cancel_button_title")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color("grey55"))
        })
        .padding()
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarColor(backgroundColor: .white, tintColor: .black)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}

func getSizeFromSerial() -> String {
    if let serial = bleManager.model?.bikeInfo?.bikeSerialNumber {
        if serial.contains("XXS"){
            return "XXS"
        }else if serial.contains("XSM") {
            return "XS"
        }else if serial.contains("SML"){
            return "S"
        }else if serial.contains("MED"){
            return "M"
        }else if serial.contains("LAR"){
            return "L"
        }
    }
    
    return "N/A"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution - using CurrentValueSubject in order to trigger dismiss and keep info about the choice made on the presented screen. Then, if registration is needed, you trigger it when sheet is dismissed.

[image]

```
    struct MainView: View {
    private let shouldShowRegistration = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    @State var isSheetPresented = false
    @State var isRegistrationPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // this part is if you want to push registration screen, you will need to have MainView inside NavigationView for it
            NavigationLink(
                destination: RegistrationView(),
                isActive: $isRegistrationPresented
            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            Button {
                isSheetPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Present sheet")
            }
            .sheet(
                isPresented: $isSheetPresented,
                onDismiss: {
                if shouldShowRegistration.value {
                    isRegistrationPresented = true
                }},
                content: {
                ChoiceView(shouldShowRegistration: shouldShowRegistration)
            })
            .onReceive(shouldShowRegistration) { shouldShowRegistration in
                isSheetPresented = false
            }
            // this part is if you want to present registration screen as sheet
            //        .sheet(
            //            isPresented: $isRegistrationPresented,
            //            content: {
            //           RegistrationView()
            //        })
        }
    }
}

    struct ChoiceView: View {
    let shouldShowRegistration: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button {
                shouldShowRegistration.send(false)
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
            
            Button {
                shouldShowRegistration.send(true)
            } label: {
                Text("Register")
            }
        }
    }
}

    struct RegistrationView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Registration")
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the post. It does work to present the view that gathers the user info. But the part where the stack need to be dismissed does not. I am having hard time with it. Possibly I am still thinking too much in therms of the UIKit framework.  I tried to use the presentationMode to drop the stack of views back to the main view but that did not work. I will update this post with some code.

Comment: I ended up replicating the same schema for the view that comes first.